# JavaScript Regexp matching part of string only

Tags: javascript, regex

OK, I need to check whether a String contains a postal code.

This is the code including Regex.

```
var isPostal = addressPickerCtrl.address.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/gi);
```

So, if I enter 1234AA all is fine, I get back the postalCode. But as soon as I enter more characters the Regexp fails. For instance "1234AA 19".

I need to check whether the whole string contains a postal code. Not a 100% match of the regexp.

(I am fairly new to Regexp)

Comment: Why do you have string boundaries ^ and $ ?

Comment: replace the anchors with word boundary.. `\b[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to check the whole string, remove the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
var isPostal = addressPickerCtrl.address.match(/[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}/gi);
```

Their purpose is exactly to force check the *whole* string by matching the start and the end of the string. See [the MDN on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: The word boundaries might turn out more appropriate in this scenario due to the lookahead (now, without anchors, it does not work as it is expected to) and `[1-9][0-9]{3}` in the beginning (that can now match even inside a longer number).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Only OP can tell for his own use case. It's for example very well possible that the first anchor *was* necessary. I'm not really providing the regex that should be used in the final code, but rather explaining so that OP can determine the most suited one.

Comment: I removed the lookahead